# code isn't transporting string back from function

Tags: c#, function

I have the following problem: I want to check if the gameName contains the predefined strings that are available inside of the function, but somehow he doesn't transport them back. I really don't know why, since they are declared in the function and should be transported back to the main part. By the way, the input for the OpenFileDialog1 is a file named: hl1-sp-the-infinite-shift.7z

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.IO;

    namespace MapTap2
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
    }
    public string CheckGame(string sourceName, string gamename)
    { 
        string hl1 = "hl1";
        string hl2 = "hl2";
        string hl2ep2 = "hl2-ep2";
        string hl2ep1 = "hl2-ep1";
        string bs = "bs";
        string prtl = "prtl";
        string prtl2 = "prtl";
        string op = "op";
        bool gamebool;



        gamebool = sourceName.Contains(hl1);
        if (gamebool == true)
        {
            gamename = "hl1";
            return gamename;
        }
            gamebool = sourceName.Contains(hl2);
        if (gamebool == true)
        {
            gamename = "hl2";
            return gamename;
        }
        gamebool = sourceName.Contains(hl2ep2);
        if (gamebool == true)
        {
            gamename = "hl2-ep2";
            return gamename;
        }
        gamebool = sourceName.Contains(hl2ep1);
        if (gamebool == true)
        {
            gamename = "hl2-ep1";
            return gamename;
        }

        gamebool = sourceName.Contains(bs);
        if (gamebool == true)
        {
            gamename = "bs";
            return gamename;
        }
        gamebool = sourceName.Contains(prtl);
        if (gamebool == true)
        {
            gamename = "prtl";
            return gamename;
        }
        gamebool = sourceName.Contains(prtl2);
        if (gamebool == true)
        {
            gamename = "prtl2";
            return gamename;
        }
        gamebool = sourceName.Contains(op);
        if (gamebool == true)
        {
            gamename = "op";
            return gamename;
        }
        else
        {
            gamename = "You sure that this file is from PP?";
            return gamename;
        }

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "7zip archives|*.7z|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
    }

    private void cmdCompress_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sourceName = "";
        string targetFolderName = "testy";


        Stream myStream;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null )
            {
                sourceName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                lblconsole.Text = sourceName;


                ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo();
                p.FileName = "7za.exe";

                p.Arguments = " e " + sourceName + " -o" + targetFolderName;

                Process x = Process.Start(p);
                x.WaitForExit(); 

                //Check the Game Version of the archive (line 20)
                string gamename = "If you see this in Debug you failed.\n Y U NO MAKE WORKING CODE?";
                CheckGame(sourceName, gamename);
                lblconsole.Text = gamename;
                }                    

        }



    }


}
```

}

Comment: Is this the minimal amount of code necessary to demonstrate the problem?  If not, please edit your question.

Comment: On a side note... look into how to use a switch statement!  Whenever you have long if-else statements, it is a good indicator it is a good sign that you should use switch!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the function, you don't actually set the return value to anything. Try doing

```
string gamename = "If you see this in Debug you failed.\n Y U NO MAKE WORKING CODE?";
gamename = CheckGame(sourceName, gamename);
lblconsole.Text = gamename;
```

As a side note, there are lots of optimizations you can make here. One being changing your `if`s and `return`s to look like:

```
    if (sourceName.Contains(hl1))
        return = hl1;
```

Happy coding

Comment: @JanWerder Added a tip. And feel free to mark as accepted answer if this solved your problem. Thx and welcome to SO. A tip for next time, just post the code that is related to the issue at hand so others don't have to sift through more than needed to :)